# Looking for a UIView subclass for iOS to render iWork, MS Office or PDF documents

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know that QLPreviewController and alike can be used, but I wish to maintain control over which page is displayed within the view. Has anyone come across such thing or would be tempted by the challenge?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: `UIWebView` provides rendering, but little in the way of controls.

Comment: Thanks, yes i'm aware of UIWebView, also understand that it ultimately rely on the QL Framework. But I'm looking for something that can just render a given page of the document in a UIView.

Comment: The QuartzDemo code sample shows how to render a page of a PDF file. But there's nothing built-in for handling the other document types you listed, other than `UIWebView` and `QLPreviewController`. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html